# How do I find the really good AVS presets for winamp?

Tags: media-player, winamp, visualization

I used to have an amazing collection of AVS presets that I slowly built up back in the day.  I had probably 500-1000 that I could just let cycle through while I watched music.  That was a while ago, and now I have no idea how to sort through the slushpile that is the winamp site to find the best presets.  Sorting by rating is nearly useless since there are so many of varying quality.

Is there a better way to browse the collection?  Is there a really good large collection somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I just use Milkdrop(1) now, sit it on random (the default) and enjoy.. its fantastic, full of thousands of presets, most of which look amazing even on low-end machines.

If you have a beast, you can REALLY crank up the graphics to take advantage, there are some nifty settings in there. (like 3D!)

As for the older AVS.. nah, too much hassle for no real benefit.

(1): The default visualisation plugin installed with winamp.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference: There's https://visbot.net, arguably the highest-quality collection out there.